# Escaping `/**` in asciidoc

Tags: filebeat, asciidoc

## My goal

I am trying to submit a fix to the [Filebeat documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration.html), written in [asciidoc](http://asciidoc.org/).

#### Source

> Currently it is not possible to recursively fetch all files in all subdirectories of a directory. However, 
>   the `/**` pattern can be used to fetch all files from a predefined level of subdirectories. For example,
>   `/var/log/**/*.log` and `/var/log/**/**/*.log` fetch all `.log` files from the subdirectories and sub-subdirectories of `/var/log`, respectively. Note that neither fetch log files from the `/var/log` folder itself.

#### Result

From [asciidoclive.com](https://asciidoclive.com/edit/scratch/1):

[image]

## My problem

The `/**` becomes `/` in the output, and the words after it are unintentionally marked in bold.

## My question

**How do I properly escape `/**` in asciidoc?**

Answer (score 5):

This is tricky, ’cause escaping is de facto broken in Asciidoctor. :(

I know about two possible workarounds:

- use passthrough: `+++\**+++`,
- or define attribute for asterisk, e.g. `:star: *` and write `\{star}{star}`.

Yes, it sucks and it’s not easily fixable in Asciidoctor. The best option would be to implement new AsciiDoc parser based on proper grammar etc, Asciidoctor is unfortunately in **very** bad shape in sense of code-quality. :( (If anyone would be willing to sponsor such project, pls contact me.)